# Regex for any string not ending on .js

Tags: regex, perl

This has been driving me nuts. I'm trying to match everything that doesn't end in `.js`. I'm using `perl`, so `?<!` etc. is more than welcome.

### What I'm trying to do:

#### Do match these

```
mainfile
jquery.1.1.11
my.module
```

#### Do **NOT** match these

```
mainfile.js
jquery.1.1.11.js
my.module.js
```

This should be an insanely simple task, but I'm just stuck. I looked in the docs for both `regex`, `sed`, `perl` and was even fiddling around for half an hour on regexr. Intuitively, [this example](http://regexr.com/39nvt) (`/^.*?(?!\.js)$/`) should do it. I guess I just stared myself blind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this regex to make sure your match doesn't end with `.js`:

```
^(?!.+\.js$).+$
```

**[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI8tL8/54)**

`(?!.+\.js$)` is a negative lookahead condition to fail the match if line has `.js` at the end.

Comment: `^(.(?!\.html$))*$` if you also want an empty string to match

Answer (score 2):

This one should suit your needs:

`^.*(?<![.]js)$`

Comment: @anubhava the question is about Perl, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach when you only have negative matching conditions is to construct a *positive regex* and then check that it doesn't match.

```
if ($string !~ /\.js$/)
{
   print "Doesn't end in .js";
}
```

This is easier to understand and more efficient than a negative look-around.

Look-arounds are only needed when you need to mix positive and negative conditions (for example, "I need to match "foo" out of a string, but only when it is not followed by "bar").  Even then, sometimes it is easier to use multiple simple patterns and logic, rather than meeting all your requirements with one complex pattern.